# No more space available even if there is a lot

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I am experiencing some weird issue lately. I am using this machine as a web server. When I try to write a file in a directory it says there is no more space. I deleted some files and it worked for a little while. After few minutes I get the problem again:

```
root@web1:/home# mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: No space left on device
root@web1:/home# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/web1-root   43G  4.5G   37G  11% /
none                   4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                   3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  798M  828K  798M   1% /run
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
none                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1              228M   91M  126M  42% /boot
/dev/sdb1              197G   75G  113G  40% /home
```

`df -i` reports a partition with 100% usage:

```
root@web1:/home# df -i | grep 100%
/dev/sdb1 13107200 13107200 0 100% /home
```

Comment: Please add the output of `df -i`

Comment: You ran out of inodes.

Comment: `df -i`
`/dev/sdb1             13107200 13107200       0  100% /home`
yes true,, hwo to solve? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the output shows high inode usage this seems to be the best answer thread out there.  It is very extensive.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117093/find-where-inodes-are-being-used

Comment: Where does the out "show high inode usage"? How did you figure that out?

Comment: @JohnRed High inode usage are posted in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Rinzwind and @heemayl suugested i ran out of inodes searching on google i foudn the answer ...
http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html

this is the solution

check available Inodes

```
$ df -i
```

find which directory is having more inodes

```
$ for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

recursivly repeat the search until you find the problem

```
$ for i in /DIRWITHHIGHINODES/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

once you found the suspect – just delete the files

```
$ sudo rm -rf /home/bad_user/directory_with_lots_of_empty_files
```

You’re done. Check the results with df -i command again. You should see something like this: